# How to save the result from equation(float) to column, python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame look line this:

`df:`

```
 1 2 3.4
-2 2 1.1
 2 3 4
-5 5 5
```

I can use this data on my equation like:

`result=abs(int(df[0])) +( int(df[1]) / 2 + float(df[2]) / 32)`

So after this calculation I receive a list with results for each line from `df` , and the resulting type is a float. 
Question: How can I save it to one column or dataframe and add this one column with `result` to the another dataframe that's same as `df` ?

I've tried `pd.DataFrame(result)`, which doesn't work.

Comment: Don't you have a KeyError on df[0] ? and int(df[{column_name}]) is not correct. You should use df[{columns_name}].astype(int)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign directly to the new column you're trying to create.

```
df[3] = abs(int(df[0])) +( int(df[1]) / 2 + float(df[2]) / 32)
```

Comment: Remember to accept an answer if this solved your problem :)

Comment: Right, the conversions don't work as written. I was assuming OP was getting the column result he intended, but simply needed to put it in a new column in the dataframe. I will update.

Comment: I only saw your comment not your answer. I was updating it for posterity. But if you think it's wrong and you'd prefer for me not to fix it, why did you even comment?

Comment: OK, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) for cast columns with [`Series.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [1, -2, 2, -5], 1: [2, 2, 3, 5], 2: [3.4, 1.1, 4.0, 5.0]})
print (df)
   0  1    2
0  1  2  3.4
1 -2  2  1.1
2  2  3  4.0
3 -5  5  5.0

df[3] = df[1].astype(int).abs() +df[1].astype(int) / 2 + df[2].astype(float) / 32
print (df)
   0  1    2         3
0  1  2  3.4  3.106250
1 -2  2  1.1  3.034375
2  2  3  4.0  4.625000
3 -5  5  5.0  7.656250
```